# EC.presence_of_element_located(*element) failing (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing my first Python Selenium page factory and am getting an error regarding my waits.

My code is as follows
Basepage Class

```
class Basepage():
    browser = None

    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser
        self.base_url = config.url

    def wait_for_element(self, *element):

        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located(*element)
        )

    def click_element(self, *element):
        self.browser.find_element(*element).click()


    def find_element(self, *element):

        self.browser.find_element(*element)
```

CreatePage Class

```
class CreatePage(Basepage):

    def isat_createpage(self):
        self.wait_for_element(*CreatePageLocators.add_computer_title)
        text = self.find_element(*CreatePageLocators.add_computer_title).text
        if text == "Add a computer":
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Behave Step
    @then('the user will be navigated to "Create_Computer" page')
    def step_impl(context):
        page = CreatePage(context.browser)
        assert page.isat_createpage(), "not at ADD Computer page"

Locator I am using for the item

```
class CreatePageLocators:
    add_computer_title = (By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"main\"]/h1")
```

I am getting the error

```
Scenario: User can open Create Computer screen              # features/UI_Tests/Create.feature:8
    Given A user has navigated to the BB_Test_Webpage         # steps/Backbase_common_steps.py:6
    And add a new computer is clicked                         # steps/Backbase_common_steps.py:11
    Then the user will be navigated to "Create_Computer" page # steps/web_create_steps.py:5
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\richard.cariven\python\lib\site-packages\behave\model.py", line 1329, in run
          match.run(runner.context)
        File "c:\users\richard.cariven\python\lib\site-packages\behave\matchers.py", line 98, in run
          self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
        File "steps\web_create_steps.py", line 8, in step_impl
          assert page.isat_createpage(), "not at ADD Computer page"
        File "C:\Users\richard.cariven\Documents\Backbase_Test_RC\modules\pages\createpage.py", line 15, in isat_createpage
          self.wait_for_element(*CreatePageLocators.add_computer_title)
        File "C:\Users\richard.cariven\Documents\Backbase_Test_RC\modules\pages\basepage.py", line 23, in wait_for_element
          EC.presence_of_element_located(*element)
      TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I imagine I am doing something very simple wrong. But help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you check the error it is mentioned about positional arguments.

> EC.presence_of_element_located(*element)
>         TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Change the following inside function like that add one more parenthesis.

```
def wait_for_element(self, *element):

        WebDriverWait(self.browser, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='main']/h1")))
```